# Joy of Mathematica

Tags: front-end

Someone has given me an old (1998) book - The Joy of Mathematica.
Alas the accompanying CD is missing from the back sleeve.
Does anyone know if there is anywhere I can download/buy the missing software please? The book states that the CD has a (Joy of Mathematica).sea file which you just drag to your hard drive and uncompressed.
Thanks
Dennis Tuckerman

Comment: First and foremost, _Mathematica_ codes from 1998 would be pretty much useless nowadays – it was [version 3.0 back then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica#Version_history), so with all the updates in the subsequent versions and extensive changes in the syntax those codes would require substantial rewriting either way.

Comment: @Leviset Why not ask WRI so they may suggest an equivalent update ?

Comment: @corey979 I think with *minor* changes the codes from 1998 will still run in the current Version 12.1.